# Does the Asterisk support SIP authentication using TLS authentciation algorithm SHA-1?

Tags: asterisk, sha1

I m using Asterisk and I want to know if the User-Agents could register with SIP  using TLS authentciation algorithm SHA-1.

Does the Asterisk support SIP authentication using TLS authentciation algorithm SHA-1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asterisk 1.8 support only md5-based auth

sha1 supported by FreeSwitch.

Asterisk 11 seams support sha-1

```
 if (!strcasecmp(hash, "sha-1")) {
                        dtls->set_fingerprint(instance, AST_RTP_DTLS_HASH_SHA1, value);
                } else {
```

Comment: do you have any proof?

Comment: Yes, chan_sip.c source file

Comment: Actualy looks like asterisk11+ support sha-1.