# what's the supported sip encryption protocols by Asterisk?

Tags: encryption, asterisk, des

Based on the following sencryption protocols, what's the supported one by Asterisk?

- RC4
- RC2
- DES
- 3DES

Are there other encryption protocols suppoorted by asterisk?

Are there an asterisk command to know the supported encryption protocols?

Comment: For what channel? IAX?SIP? PRI? For which task? Which asterisk version?

Comment: @arheops SIP channel, for the astrisk 1.8.10.1 version and the last version

Comment: 1.8.* not do encryption at all.

Comment: @arheops. what about the `tlsenable` parammter in the `sip.conf.sample`. I checked the 1.8.* source and I found that the TLS is enabled for sip

Comment: Never tried TLS,sorry. I use kamailio for TLS. But you always can read chan_sip.c. TLS in 1.8 is very limited and not encrypt sip messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regards to SIP, Asterisk (via chan_sip) supports encryption of both the signalling and the media. Arheops comment that Asterisk 1.8 doesn't support encryption is incorrect; this is true in Asterisk 1.8 and all later versions. For more information, see the [Secure Calling](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Secure+Calling) section on the Asterisk [wiki](https://wiki.asterisk.org).

Signalling is encrypted using OpenSSL (yes, the one with the vulnerability. Upgrade if you haven't). It defers encryption of the SIP signalling to OpenSSL. Which [cipher](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER_SUITE_NAMES) is used is dependent on the version of OpenSSL you have installed, as well as what you configure in [sip.conf](http://svn.asterisk.org/svn/asterisk/branches/1.8/configs/sip.conf.sample), via the tlscipher option.

```
;tlscipher=<SSL cipher string>
;        A string specifying which SSL ciphers to use or not use
;        A list of valid SSL cipher strings can be found at:
;                http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/ciphers.html#CIPHER_STRINGS
;
```

Asterisk supports encryption of the media in one of two ways. The first, supported in Asterisk 1.8 and later, is [SDES-SRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Real-time_Transport_Protocol), via the libsrtp library. libsrtp uses AES as the default cipher.

As SDES-SRTP has to exchange keys in plain text in the signalling, another method of encrypting the media is available in Asterisk 11 and later, DTLS-SRTP. This uses OpenSSL's [DTLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Transport_Layer_Security) capabilities (available in more recent versions) to exchange the keys between the participants in the encrypted media stream. Note that this is the mechanism mandated by WebRTC (whereas SDES-SRTP got slapped down with a "SHOULD NOT" be implemented).

On a final note, in Asterisk 12, the [new SIP stack](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Configuring+res_pjsip) (based on PJSIP), also supports all of these various encryption mechanisms.

Comment: Does Asterisk use OpenSSL (TLS) in the **authentication** too? Does Asterisk support sha-1 in the **autentication**?

Comment: Could you please check the answer in this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23157257/does-the-asterisk-support-sip-authentication-using-tls-authentciation-algorithm). The answer say that sha-1 authentication is not supported in asterisk 1.8.*

Comment: No, it does not use OpenSSL to process the digest. That is done using MD5. It does not support SHA-1 for that. Note that this is all pretty much documented in the sample configuration file for chan_sip.